# Unable to configure the .gitattributes to have any effect for merges

Tags: git, gitattributes

The `merge` driver for `.gitattributes` has been configured:

```
git config --global merge.ours.driver true

$git config -l
push.default=current
pull.default=current
merge.ours.driver=true
```

Here is what is in the repo's `gitattributes` file (under `.git/info/attributes`):

```
$cat .git/info/attributes

keys_manager/* merge=ours
js/README.md merge=theirs
```

The `keys_manager` directory had been removed in the first branch (ours) and a change made to it in the second (theirs) branch.  Changes have been made to a file inside of `keys_manager` on the remote end  and to the `js/README.md` on both branches.

Let us now do a dry-run of the commit:

```
git merge --no-commit --no-ff origin/audiorec
```

The result:

```
CONFLICT (modify/delete): keys_manager/init_db.sql deleted in HEAD and modified in 
origin/audio-recorder. Version origin/audio-recorder of keys_manager/init_db.sql left in tree.

Auto-merging js/README.md
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in js/README.md
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
```

These are not the expected `.gitattributes` influenced results but rather the vanilla results as if the `.gitattributes` did not exist. Why is it not taking effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your merge driver would be used for `keys_manager/init_db.sql` if there were a *low-level* conflict.  But in fact:

> ```
> CONFLICT (modify/delete): keys_manager/init_db.sql deleted in HEAD
> and modified in origin/audio-recorder ... [snip]
> ```

you got a *high-level* or *tree* conflict, instead of a low-level conflict.  That is, one side completely deleted the file, and the other side modified the file.  The standard merge strategy always just leaves the modified file as the temporary (conflicted) result, and stops with a conflict.  If you would like for the final result to have the file deleted, you may simply delete the file now.

Meanwhile, this:

> ```
> Auto-merging js/README.md
> CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in js/README.md
> ```

*is* a low-level conflict, so your merge driver:

> ```
> js/README.md merge=theirs
> ```

should have been invoked.  You showed:

> ```
> merge.ours.driver=true
> ```

but what is `merge.theirs.driver` set to?  If not set, the instructions to use your own driver are ignored; Git uses its built-in low-level merge driver.

Comment: Thanks for these details. I did not run into the specific instructions/ documentation requiring both sides of `merge.[ours|theirs].driver`  and had just copied what I had found in some commentary